# How to disable hover effect for the transition or animation time then enable it after the transition or animation is finished in css?

Tags: css, animation, hover, transform

I want to disable or deactivate the hover effect until the transition is finished and then reactivate the
hover effect. So, I simply want to disable the hover effect for a certain amount of time so the transition is being completed. I already used transition-delay but it is not that I want. Thank You in Advance. Here is my code.

```css
#one
{
    color: green;
    border: 0px solid red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
/*I want to disable this hover until the transition is over*/
#one:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    transform: translate(-15px,-15px) rotate3d(1,1,1,360deg) scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this using an animation, along with some `JavaScript`. When the user hovers over `#one`, we add a `hover` class to the `body`, which the `#one` element will respond to. At this point, `#one` includes `pointer-events: none` to ensure that any extra hovering will not re-trigger the animation. After the animation ends, we remove the `hover` class from `body`, allowing the animation to once again begin after a new hover event is registered.

```js
const one = document.getElementById("one");

one.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("hover"); 
});

one.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
  document.body.classList.remove("hover");
});
```

```css
@keyframes oneAnimation {
  to {
    transform: translate(-15px, -15px) rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 360deg) scale(1.1);
  }
}

#one {
  color: green;
  border: 0px solid red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.hover #one {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  animation: oneAnimation 1s forwards 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/k6vwmh45/21/)